# AJAX works online but not on my computer

Tags: ajax

I've been having problems testing AJAX on my computer, the code works fine online but not on my system, is there something I am missing?

I've had this problem with pretty much any kind of AJAX and even some javascript code. I know the code itself is correctly since it's functioning online as intended, but why wouldn't run on my PC? Everything I am trying to do is basic coding, no database, or advanced functions of any kind, simple interface changes and such.

I don't have any specific code to post since its a general problem i'm having, but any thoughts are appreciated. Could it be a document type issue? I tried blank and a couple of others but none seemed to matter.

Comment: is your PC running a web server?  IIS?  Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Ill bet that you are having a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue.  If you are loading the page by going to `localhost:<port>/app` and then your javascript tries to go to anywhere other than localhost the browser will stop it for violating the policy.

Answer (score 0):

I have had strange problems testing AJAX locally before.  To fix this I install ultidev's Cassini web server and run the application on that and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a webserver with either php running or something like it. A desktop PC is not a web server by default.